# Android App: Navigation is hectic. Could it be simplified?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the StackExchange App for android. Every time I visit a question and then click links inside which are references to another questions or a user profile and then want to return to the main feeds screen again, I have to navigate through all the screens i came through. Is there a plan to include a skip-to-home button in near future?